# Error - Highlighting results - No matching windows found

Tags: blueprism

I use Windows Application to spy security popup for username and password. Then I use Navigate to Attach it. Once click OK, web page appear. I couldn't spy the drop down list using this business object. It prompt me error: Error - Highlighting results - No matching windows found

I'm using UI automation mode to identify.

How can I spy the drop down list?

Comment: Before interacting with the webpage again, did you detach and re-attach to the web browser?

Comment: so i need to detach and spy the drop down list? or detach --> attach then spy?

Comment: The latter... you can't spy anything without being attached to the application in question.

Comment: I manage to spy the drop down list. I use the navigate to read the drop down list from select item but failed. Any idea how can I input the drop down list value?

Answer (score 0):

Do you like to read the entries of the dropdown as an single string or do you like to get each single item?
So in case 2. you should work with dynamic attributes.
Spy element 1 and element 2 of the dropdown list.
Compare them and use a data item in an appropriate connector. With connector I mean something like "WebPath". This data item should be increased in order to get all drop down entries.